# How to get back to a site when viewing one of its questions

Tags: feature-request, android-app, question-lists, navigation

When viewing a question on a site which I don't use (I never registered on it), I can't figure out how to get back to the list of questions of the site.

See this example [What female mathematician can I introduce to my High School students?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/1817) from the Stack Exchange Android app. Where should I *click* to see the list of questions? (I chose Mathematics Educators because it's the most recent site, it is very likely that most users don't have an account on this website)

Here is a random example:

[image: Question]

When viewing a question, I don't know how to view the list of questions. This site can't be found in the sidebar since it's not in my *Your Sites* list. The top menu containing the site's title only opens the sidebar.

Comment: There should be a better way, but for now a workaround: tap any tag of the question (this will bring up search results for the tag), then tap `x` to clear the search.

Comment: Assuming it's similar to the iOS app, instead of tapping the question, tap the site logo.

Comment: Yes I discovered it after having posted this question. But it only works on the first screenshot (the Feed), not on the second. So if you follow a direct link to a question, how do you get to the questions list?

Comment: You have to go back

Comment: I tried this from this question: I opened this question in the app, clicked on the link in it then clicked on *back*, it just display this question again.

Comment: then that's a bug. Back works fine in iOS

Comment: @mhlester I don't think it's a bug, since *historically* you open this question, then open another question thru link from here. Pressing `back` button will return back to this question, just like browser's `back` behavior. So, if I understood your comment, after opening that link, pressing back will go to Mathematics Educators question list instead?

Comment: In the iOS app, pressing back returns to the feed, at which point you tap the icon of the site to see its questions. That isn't working on android though?

Comment: Do you see any icon on the second screenshot?

Comment: I think we are talking 2 different cases: One for hot question from feeds (screenshot), the other for question linked in another question (part of question body). The one that I referred to is the second case, while *I think* you referred to the first one. For first case, Pressing back does return to the feeds and user can press the logo to go to that site. But for second case, I assume the behavior in iOS is the same as I explained before and the only workaround is to tap the tag. Just want to clarify the matters...

Comment: Sorry for double comment, but I have to add some info for the first case: it only applies to hot questions for 1 site. Tapping the logo on hot questions with mixed sites don't do anything (not related to this post, probably a bug or status-by-design, I have yet to ask)

Comment: I've updated the question to remove the first screenshot, my question is much clearer now. @AndrewT.: feel free to add a new question for this *Hot questions* problem.