# If I'm looking at a question, how do I get back to the site the question is on?

Tags: support, android-app

Maybe I'm just stupid, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to get from a question (in the Android App) to the site the question is on.

I know I can open the left drawer, tap "All Sites", and type in the name of the site I want to go to, but it seems like there should be a way to get from a question to its site without all that rigmarole. (Tapping the back button works if I was on the site in the first place, but if I get to a question from my feed or from a link in my browser or something, that doesn't help.)

Comment: Is it different from my question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230131/237701

Comment: @A.L Nope, looks like the same question. VTCing as duplicate, thanks.

Comment: senshin: fun and useless fact: I just discovered (thanks to related questions) that my question was a duplicate too!

Answer (score 3):

Having a look at it, the fastest way appears to be to click on a tag (all questions have tags):

[image: Click a tag]

And then dismiss the tag from the search with the little **`(x)`** icon:

[image: Dismiss the tag]

And then you're on the questions page for the site:

[image: Done]

While it's still a bit fiddly, it's certainly quicker than what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely better. In hopes that there might be an _even_ better way of doing this, I'm going to leave this unaccepted for a while.