# Add option to navigate from promoted question to that sites list page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

On the iOS mobile app I get interesting questions from across the exchange network. Occasionally I click on one as it peaks my interest (I'm guessing that was the design intent).... Let's say a "Puzzling" question.

I'm intrigued now and want to see other questions from this site... I can't see a simple way to get such a view and clicking the name of the site just takes me back to that specific question.

It is even worse when the question is on a network I follow... I can't jump to the list from there either.

E.g. This is the screen I'm taken to:
[image]

And the back arrow in the top left just takes me to my "SE home screen"

Comment: *You are a Spoiler*, nice coincidence here :D

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234644/if-im-looking-at-a-question-how-do-i-get-back-to-the-site-the-question-is-on (suggested workaround might also work in your case.)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this.

If you long press on the site name in the navigation bar (really the title and site name), it brings up a context menu to switch sites:

> [image: Screenshot showing navigation bar menu.]

The other is from the question action bar.  Tap "More" then "Switch to Site".

> [image: Screenshot showing question action menu.]

Comment: Ah cool that will work.